# VBA to Format Multiple Table Ranges in different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, range, worksheet

I have list of worksheets, table names, column names and format details in columns B, C, D and E in a worksheet and I want the VBA macro to loop through this list to apply formatting in the respective worksheet's table/name range columns Or All Columns.

please see the below table and the code I have so far.. can someone help with amending the below code to make it work as per my expectation

| # | Worksheet Name | Table Name / Range Name | Column Names | Format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Philip | Philip_Test3 | Commentary, Date, Time Stamp, Region | CustomFormat |
| 2 | Edward | Edward_Test8 | City, Region, Template Name | CustomFormat |
| 3 | Jessica | Jessica_Test2 | Date, Time Stamp, Region | CustomFormat1 |
| 4 | Tony | Tony_Test1 | Commentary, Time Stamp, Region, Template Name | CustomFormat |
| 4 | Roger | Roger_TestNew | All Columns | CustomFormat1 |

```
Option Explicit
Sub FormatMultipleRanges()
  Dim Cell As Range
   Dim nm As Name
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = sht.Range("D2:D9")
    
    Dim FormatRng As Range
    Set FormatRng = sht.Range("E2:E9")

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sht.Name, Range("B2:B9"), 0)) Then
        
        For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name, Range("C2:C9"), 0)) Then

For Each Cell In myRange
    CustomFormat (myRange)
Next myRange
      '
          
        End If
        
    Next
End Sub
```

formatting function

```
public function CustomFormat(rng as excel.range) 

rng.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
rng.WrapText = True    

end function

public function CustomFormat1(rng as excel.range) 

rng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
rng.WrapText = True    

end function
```

Comment: Please, [don't post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, or will throw errors if you're not using `Option Explicit` - you've not defined `ws`, your CustomFormat function has got a double `..`.  It also doesn't seem to reference the images you posted?

Answer (score 0):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListColumn.DataBodyRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumn.databodyrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm738082)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```
Option Explicit
Sub FormatMultipleRanges()
    Dim i As Long, aCol, iVertical As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, oTab As ListObject, oRng As Range
    Dim desSht As Worksheet, arrData
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Loop through table
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Get sheet object
        On Error Resume Next
        Set desSht = Worksheets(arrData(i, 2))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not desSht Is Nothing Then
            If desSht.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
                ' Get table (listobject) object
                On Error Resume Next
                Set oTab = desSht.ListObjects(arrData(i, 3))
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not oTab Is Nothing Then
                    ' Get the VerticalAlignment setting
                    iVertical = 0
                    If StrComp(arrData(i, 5), "CustomFormat", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        iVertical = xlTop
                    ElseIf StrComp(arrData(i, 5), "CustomFormat1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        iVertical = xlCenter
                    End If
                    If iVertical <> 0 Then
                        ' Format cols
                        For Each aCol In Split(arrData(i, 4), ",")
                            ' If Col aCol exists in oTab
                            On Error Resume Next
                            Set oRng = oTab.ListColumns(Trim(aCol)).DataBodyRange
                            On Error GoTo 0
                            If Not oRng Is Nothing Then
                                oRng.VerticalAlignment = iVertical
                                oRng.WrapText = True
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Set desSht = Nothing
        Set oTab = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Update:

```vb
Sub FormatMultipleRanges()
    Dim i As Long, aCol, iVertical As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, oTab As ListObject, oRng As Range
    Dim desSht As Worksheet, arrData
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Loop through table
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Get sheet object
        On Error Resume Next
        Set desSht = Worksheets(arrData(i, 2))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not desSht Is Nothing Then
            If desSht.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
                ' Get table (listobject) object
                On Error Resume Next
                Set oTab = desSht.ListObjects(arrData(i, 3))
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not oTab Is Nothing Then
                    For Each aCol In Split(arrData(i, 4), ",")
                        ' All columns in oTab
                        If StrComp("All Columns", aCol, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            Set oRng = oTab.DataBodyRange
                        Else
                            ' If Col aCol exists in oTab
                            On Error Resume Next
                            Set oRng = oTab.ListColumns(Trim(aCol)).DataBodyRange
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        End If
                        If Not oRng Is Nothing Then
                            If StrComp(arrData(i, 5), "CustomFormat", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                                Call CustomFormat(oRng)
                            ElseIf StrComp(arrData(i, 5), "CustomFormat1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                                Call CustomFormat1(oRng)
                                ' ElseIf ' modify as needed, add more conditions
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Set desSht = Nothing
        Set oTab = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub CustomFormat(rng As Excel.Range)
    rng.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    rng.WrapText = True
End Sub
Public Sub CustomFormat1(rng As Excel.Range)
    rng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    rng.WrapText = True
End Sub
```

---

Update2:

```vb
Sub FormatMultipleRanges2()
    Dim i As Long, aCol, iVertical As Long, j As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, oRng As Range
    Dim desSht As Worksheet, arrData, rngTab As Range, RowCnt As Long
    'Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet") ' modify as needed
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Loop through table
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Get sheet object
        On Error Resume Next
        Set desSht = Worksheets(arrData(i, 2))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not desSht Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next
            If desSht.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
                ' Get table (listobject) object
                Set rngTab = desSht.ListObjects(arrData(i, 3)).Range
            End If
            If rngTab Is Nothing Then
                ' Get the named range
                Set rngTab = desSht.Range(arrData(i, 3))
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngTab Is Nothing Then
                RowCnt = rngTab.Rows.Count
                For Each aCol In Split(arrData(i, 4), ",")
                    ' All columns
                    If StrComp("All Columns", aCol, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        Set oRng = rngTab.Resize(RowCnt - 1).Offset(1)
                    Else
                        For j = 1 To rngTab.Columns.Count
                            If StrComp(aCol, rngTab.Cells(1, j).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                                Set oRng = rngTab.Columns(j).Resize(RowCnt - 1).Offset(1)
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If Not oRng Is Nothing Then
                        If StrComp(arrData(i, 5), "CustomFormat", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            Call CustomFormat(oRng)
                        ElseIf StrComp(arrData(i, 5), "CustomFormat1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            Call CustomFormat1(oRng)
                            ' ElseIf ' modify as needed, add more conditions
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
        Set desSht = Nothing
        Set oTab = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response. really appreciate it. just 2 more things.. 
1. In "Column Names" .i.e. column 4 I may have to enter All Worksheets.. so can we tweak it add that condition
2. The customformat and customformat1 are just examples of 2 formatting functions there could be more, so can we just run the function which is being entered in the rows of column 5 for each of the range .i.e. looping to through list.
thanks again

Comment: What does `enter All Worksheets` mean? Do you mean format all columns within a table (listobject)? I'd think you'd better to edit your post to include exptected output.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post... ad in my previous comment I had erroneously mentioned All Worksheets instead of All Columns so now I have added a last row in the table which has the example where I want the formatting to be applied to all columns of a table/range and right now this works with tables but not name ranges...can we tweak this to work for both

Comment: apart from this.. The customformat and customformat1 are just examples of 2 formatting functions and there could be more, so can we just run the function which is being entered in the rows of column 5 for each of the range .i.e. looping to through list. thanks again

Comment: `there could be more` the code can loop through. Please update the sample data in your post. What's the delimiter?  eg. If it is `CustomFormat,CustomFormat1`, how to handle the conficted format (VerticalAlignment setting)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion when I say there could be more.. it does not mean that in column 5 .i.e. Format Column I will have 2 or 3 CustomFormat separated by commas. The format column (column 5) will just have only one format .i.e. either customformat, or customformat1 or customformat2 or customformat3 and so on.. so basically it will have only one format function in one row but I don't want to hard the function details in macro..i want to keep them as separate function and that's the reason I wanted to mention function name in format column.

Comment: Also I had erroneously mentioned All Worksheets instead of All Columns so now I have added a last row in the table which has the example where I want the formatting to be applied to all columns of a table/range and right now this works with tables but not name ranges...can we tweak this to work for both tables and name ranges.

Comment: You can maintain the formatting as a standalone function. However, since you're not returning a value, it's more appropriate to use Sub instead of Function. I've updated the code.

Comment: Great. thanks a lot. really appreciate it. the function and all columns requirement is sorted now but still there is one problem which I had mentioned earlier .i.e. in Table / Range Name Column (Column 3) if I have a Name Range instead of Table then it doesn't work. Can we tweak it to work for both Table and Name Range..

Comment: I've updated the code w/o testing. Please try `Update2`.

Comment: Ok. I just tested it, it shows the below error on the following line

error msg: Run time error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method
it shows this error on line "If StrComp(aCol, rngTab.Cell(1, j).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then"

Comment: If StrComp(aCol, rngTab.Cells(1, j).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

Comment: It's not showing any error but its not working either for name range in fact with update2 its not working properly for the rows where I have tables for e.g. In row 2 I have three columns in column names column .i.e. City, Region and Template name and for some reason with update2 it doesn't format the region column same thing happens for other rows but when I use update version then it works properly but since its just for tables it works for all the rows where I have tables and not for the row where I have name range, if using name range is problem then I can put the range as A2:F2000

Comment: I've tested `FormatMultipleRanges2()` against `named range` and `listobject` w/o any issue. I guess the reason of your failure is a wrong active sheet. `Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` is from the original code in your post. I would suggest change it to `Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet")`. It is more reliable to get the control table.